# JSTree preserve node style after close / open parent node

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have simple tree implemented using JSTree, I need to change specific node style using JQuery, my problem is when closing the parent node and open it again the changes on that node is discarded,

Here is a jsFiddle that contains my code:

```
<div id="stations_tree">
  <ul>
    <li>root1</li>
    <li>root2</li>
    <li>root3
      <ul>
        <li id="child1">child1</li>
        <li id="child2">child2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Change color"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stations_tree').jstree({
        "plugins" : [ "types" ], 
        "types" : {
            "default" : {
                "icon" : "fa fa-circle"
            },
            "station" : {
                "icon" : "fa fa-circle"
            }
        }, 
        "core" : {
            "multiple" : false
        }
    }).bind("open_node.jstree close_node.jstree", function (e, data) {

    });

    $("#stations_tree").jstree("open_all");
});  

$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#child1").css("color","green");
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m_kaleia/vdbb0hdx/

How to preserve nodes styles after reopening parent nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Add the style attribute to the 'child1' node.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#child1").css("color","green");
    var node = $("#stations_tree").jstree(true).get_node('child1');
    node.a_attr['style']= 'color:green';
});
```